# Contract violation (make-array) in Racket

Tags: racket

I want to make an array which is 1xn, where n is the maximum value that occurs in some input array (which will contain only integers). 
I checked the type of get-max with the sample input array below. Its type is an integer. (Note, describe is from the library (planet williams/describe/describe)))

```
>> (describe (array-ref (array-axis-max A 0) #()))
6 is a byte (i.e., an exact positive integer fixnum between 0 and 255 inclusive) six
```

Here's my code to produce the array:

```
(define (array-from-max input)
  (local ((define get-max (array-ref (array-axis-max input 0) #())))
    (make-array #(get-max) 0)))
```

However, the following call yields the error below it. make-array expects an integer but is given 'get-max.

Question 1: Am I really passing a symbol-value into make-array?

Question 2: How can I successfully pass the result of (array-axis-max) into the size argument of (make-array)?

Question 3: Is what's inside #() evaluated? How is it evaluated?

```
>> (array-from-max (array #[3 6 4 1 3 4 1 4]))
make-array: contract violation
  expected: Integer
  given: 'get-max
  in: an element of
      the 1st argument of
      (->
       (vectorof Integer)
       any/c
       (struct/c
        Array
        (vectorof Index)
        any/c
        (box/c (or/c #f #t))
        (-> any)
        (-> (vectorof Index) any)))
```

Comment: Note that I do know a lot of contract violation Racket questions have been asked, but I can't find/recognize which one is applicable here.

Comment: #(...) is reader syntax for a literal vector, similar to how '(...) is a literal list. Anything inside the literal is assumed to also be literal, so #(foo) produces a vector containing the symbol 'foo rather than a vector containing the value of a variable named foo, in the same way that '(foo) produces a list with the symbol foo. Not posting this as an answer since I can't reproduce your error - I'm getting some weird polymorphic typechecking error in `(array-axis-max input 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: yep, just like Jack said above. The `#` is like the `"` for strings -- once you're inside, characters are taken literally.

Question 2: use `(vector get-max)`. Here's an example

```
#lang racket
(require math/array)

(define (array-from-max input)
  (local ((define get-max (array-ref (array-axis-max input 0) #())))
      (make-array (vector get-max) 0)))

(array-from-max (array #[3 6 4 1 3 4 1 4]))
```

Question 3: things inside the `#()` are automatically quoted, as specified in [Vectors](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/vectors.html) from the racket guide